# ASP.NET Core RC2 Seed Data using Services

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

I've been using ASP.NET 5 RC1 in which I've an application in which I seed administrative credentials into the data base using Services as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddEntityFramework()
                .AddSqlServer()
                .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

        services.AddIdentity<AdministratorUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddTransient<AdministratorSeedData>();
    }
```

Here is the connection string sub-object:

```
 "ConnectionString": "Server=.;Database=kjanshair;Trusted_Connection=True;"
```

And the service that I use to seed data is being seeded using the Administrative seed data. It all works fine but when I port it to RC2, with the following changes in the startup as:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddTransient<AdministratorSeedData>();
    }
```

with the connection string as:

```
"ConnectionString": "Server=.;Database=_CHANGE_ME;Trusted_Connection=True;"
```

I get an exception in Configure() method

```
public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, AdministratorSeedData seeder)
    {
        app.UseIdentity();

        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

        await seeder.EnsureSeedData(); //Here exception occurs
    }
```

saying as:

```
Message = "Cannot open database \"_CHANGE_ME\" requested by the login. The login failed.\r\nLogin failed for user 'DESKTOP-55E4D9H\\Janshair Khan'."
```

Why Am I getting this error? I've looked all over the alternatives but couldn't resolved.

Comment: Check Julie lerman "data farm" latest post. Might help u

Answer (score 0):

I think you can fix it by changing like this:

```
services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer()
    .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(serviceProvider, options => 
      options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"])
    .UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider)
    );
```

also make sure your DbContext has the constructor like this:

```
public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
{

}
```

I ran into the same problem and that got it working for me

Comment: The method `AddSqlServer()` is compatible with RC1. Official ASP.NET Core works without this method. But how that is working?

Comment: sorry I had a mistake in my solution, I just fixed it

Comment: you should show the code for how you add your appsettings.json or other config sources, it doesn't seem like it is getting your connection string from the right place.  there are some needed changes for rc2 in configuration how you set the base path

Comment: I'm following the default template configuration method, I'm setting the base path in the constructor as the base path the same as template showed as

`public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);

            builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }`

Comment: in the latest template they use Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") maybe try changing your appsettings the same as new projects, that is what I did now that I look closer

Comment: Still don't working, I tried to change the code but nothing happens.

Comment: The code is also not working with the latest template, neither on localdb nor on SQL Server instance. Don't know what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've identified the problem and now eventually solved it. The problem was the change in the Identity ecosystem of RC2. I added the migrations using by typing in the terminal as:

```
dotnet ef migrations add "migration message"
```

, update the database

```
dotnet ef database update
```

and now I'm able to seed the data in my database.